# How to transform from CMake to a plain Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am able to CMake build this [HelloWorld example project](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/tree/master/examples/helloworld) using [cmakelists.txt](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/blob/master/examples/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt) file and generate a visual studio project.

```
project(helloworld LANGUAGES C CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

find_package(Idlpp-cxx REQUIRED)
if (NOT TARGET CycloneDDS-CXX::ddscxx)
  find_package(CycloneDDS-CXX REQUIRED)
endif()

# Convenience function, provided by the Idlpp-cxx that generates a CMake
# target for the given IDL file. The function calls Idlcpp-cxx to generate
# source files and compiles them into a library.
idl_ddscxx_generate(ddscxxHelloWorldData_lib "HelloWorldData.idl")

add_executable(ddscxxHelloworldPublisher publisher.cpp)
add_executable(ddscxxHelloworldSubscriber subscriber.cpp)

# Link both executables to idl data type library and ddscxx.
target_link_libraries(ddscxxHelloworldPublisher ddscxxHelloWorldData_lib     CycloneDDS-CXX::ddscxx)
target_link_libraries(ddscxxHelloworldSubscriber ddscxxHelloWorldData_lib CycloneDDS-CXX::ddscxx)

set_property(TARGET ddscxxHelloworldPublisher PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET ddscxxHelloworldSubscriber PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

I need to create the same project without [cmakelists.txt](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/blob/master/examples/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt) and CMake

How to do this only using visual studio? **where to define those commands in CMakelists.txt** in visual studio **if I create an empty c++ project**

I have tried this making an empty project.

I don't know how to idl_ddscxx_generate and target_link_libraries perform in VS....

idl_ddscxx_generate has to run if IDL file has changed
target_link_libraries is required if I added new source files to the project....

Comment: have you tried creating a project? where did you get stuck? why don't you want to use cmake if you already have it working?

Comment: @Alan Birtles if I have to include new source files I have to add them to the CMakelists. which I cannot do in a production environment...

Comment: @Alan Birtles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#CreateLibProject  ......i followed this, did the same thing, and set additional c++ dependencies and linker inputs into the empty c++ VS project....according to properties in the project I created using the above cmakelists.txt file

Comment: if you're using visual studio projects you'll also need to add your new source files to those, I don't see the difference

Comment: @Alan Birtles yeah but here i have to modify cmakelist and CMake build.... I need to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a new, empty Visual Studio project.
2. Copy all source files except the CMake files.
3. Do whatever you do in a Visual Studio project. Add files, targets, dependecies, … If you are not sure, look up what is written in the CMakeLists.txt file.
4. Delete all CMake files in your original project and copy your Visual Studio project files.
5. Add these changes (deleted CMake files, added VS project files) to your Subversion repository, maybe do this in a branch that others can test it, report back, and improve the change. Once done, merge the branch.

Probably, add step 0.: Learn how Visual Studio organizes its project. Make a tutorial, take some training.

Remark: Whatever your problem is with CMake, you missed something. But you can find this out later and revert your changes and pick up CMake up again.

Comment: can you explain how to include idl_ddscxx_generate to plain VS project? where should i add it?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to do this at all without a proper build system like CMake.